# How do I calculate penalty fees incrementally in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate penalty fees incrementally, the program must take the value of the first calculation and add it to the second and give total to be printed.

Here is my code:

```
if days >= 1 and days <= 4:
  payment = days * 3
  print("Payment is: ", "$", payment)
  
elif days >= 5 and days <= 10:
  payment = days * 5
  print("Payment is: ", "$", payment)
```

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct is to loop and maintain a count.

try the following solution:

change the range around since the values generated by range function starts from 0

```py
total_penalty = 0
for i in range(total_delay):
    if i < 4:
        total_penalty += 3
    elif i >= 4 and i <= 9:
        total_penalty += 5  

print(total_penalty)
```

Comment: Am I missing something or what, but this does produce completely different values from the solution provided by the OP?

Comment: @DocDriven Question was modified after I answered and before you viewed. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, actual amount and default days is given as input to this function.

```
def penalty(actual_amt,days):
    penalty_amt = 0
    if days == 0:
        print('No Penalty')
    elif days >=1 and days <=5:
        penalty_amt = actual_amt + ( days * 3 )
    elif days > 5 and days <=10:
        penalty_amt = actual_amt + ( days * 5 )
   
    print(f'Your total cost with penalty is {penalty_amt}') 
    return penalty_amt
```